# Wii remote -> InputDevice?

Tags: input-methods, game-controllers

Does anyone know of a Wii remote enabler that maps the remote onto an Android InputDevice, the same way that gamepads etc work?

I've found lots of Wii remote apps on the market, but they all map the remote to the Android keyboard, which isn't what I want --- we have an application with support for multiple gamepads via the InputDevice API, and we'd like to use a Wii remote with it.

I'm willing to use an app that needs root.